# LINQ and paging with a DataTable - can't get Skip working?

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

Ok so this might be a dumb question, but I can't seem to figure it out. I thought I'd try out LINQ against a DataTable. I got my query working and now I'm trying to implement some simple paging.

```
DataTable dataTable = null;

dataTable = GetAllDataTables();

var query = from r in dataTable.AsEnumerable()
            orderby r.Field<string>(Constants.fileName)
            select r;

query.Skip(WPP_PAGE_SIZE * pageIndex).Take(WPP_PAGE_SIZE);
```

My problem is that I get an error at query.Skip(...).

> Error 1   'System.Data.OrderedEnumerableRowCollection'
>   does not contain a definition for
>   'Skip' and no extension method 'Skip'
>   accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Data.OrderedEnumerableRowCollection'
>   could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

References I have:

- Microsoft.SharePoint
- System
- System.Core
- System.Data
- System.Data.DataSetExtensions
- System.Web
- System.Xml

What am I missing?

Comment: I suppose there is a `using System.Linq`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need `using System.Linq;` at the top of your file.

A second problem is that you need to assign the result of Skip and Take to something otherwise the result is simply discarded:

```
var query2 = query.Skip(WPP_PAGE_SIZE * pageIndex).Take(WPP_PAGE_SIZE);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
using System.Linq?
```